Is it ok to use a wood screw with a washer when installing outside lamp into metal mounting bracket but also screws into the wall
I had 2 hard grounding wires coming out of the wall and had a thin wire from the outside light I was installing. The grounding screw was just too short so I found a screw that along with a washer would fit into the grounding screw hole on the metal plate and hold all wires tightly - however the screw is also screwed into the wood outside wall.  Is this a hazard or ok since all wires are connected to the mounting bracket?

Be better to pigtail the three grounds to a long enough ground wire and connect that to the proper ground screw(that you kept).
Most electrical screws are for one wire under the head.  Some are labelled/listed(see instructions) for two wires.
If there is more than one wire to be connected to a screw not listed for more than one, then you pigtail/connect the wires with a wire nut/lever action connector(wago) and connect one wire from the connector to the screw.
Electrical stuff is listed/labelled for electrical use.  Using non listed stuff(even if it looks the same) is not allowed.  Some metal/plastic electric conduit looks the same as metal/plastic plumbing pipes(cheaper usually), but you cannot use plumbing pipes to run electric wires.
